# Workflow application in c#

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a workflow application hosted (for now) in a Console Application, using WorkflowServiceHost to host an activity. This was based on a MS example, and works fine.

I'd like to add another 'WebMethod' to this application. This method has nothing to do with the workflow being hosted - it will simply be a 'ping' service so that clients can tell that the application is alive and running.

Is this even possible? If so, how would I go about adding this new method?

Thanks

Comment: I have discovered that MS offer some additional 'endpoints' which can be added to a Workflow project. These do things like control the workflow - creating new instances and resuming bookmarks, but it doesn't seem possible to modify these to add the functionality I require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a new method inside the Console Application as that would be poor practise (1 thing should do 1 job)

Instead create a new WCF project inside your solution.
Reference this project in your Console app and start the WCF host when the Console app initializes.

The WCF project can then be written to respond to 'ping' requests.

This is a handy primer in WCF 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows

Answer (score 0):

Richard,

Thanks for your answer. I was able to add a new endpoint to the Console App but defining the service interface, and adding another host and starting it.

This is fine for the proof-of-concept code, but wouldn't be acceptable for release.

Dave